# How to add language links to the MediaWiki sidebar?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I've installed a **MediaWiki** site and I have configured it to have a [multilingual wiki](http://www.steverumberg.com/wiki/WikiHelp_-_Method_Two). To do that I have created a folder for each wiki (for example for English language: `/home/fuiba/en/`, for German language: `/home/fuiba/de/` ) and all the folders have a symbolic links to the source code, so I have the same source code for all wikis, and the same database, but with its own tables.

Then I created many sub-domains for each language that points to the folder relative the wiki (*www.en.site.com* points to `/home/fuiba/en/`, *www.de.site.com* points to `/home/fuiba/en/`).

In the *www.en.site.com/wiki/Main_Page* I want to add the languages links in the Sidebar, like Wikipedia:

[image]

I checked the Sidebar page (*MediaWiki:Sidebar*) and there is a link for the Languages:

```
 * LANGUAGES
```

but I don't see the languages link on the Sidebar. How do I add theme?

Comment: Do your pages have [interlanguage links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Interlanguage_links)?

Comment: No. But I tried to insert in my page `[[de:page]] [[fr:page]]` but I don't get the languages list in the sidebar. Probably I have to install this extension: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Interlanguage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Manual page for this on mw.org:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interwiki#Interwiki_links_to_other_languages

You just need to do these steps and after this you can use the markup [[iwcode:Pagename]] (where iwcode the language prefix and Pagename the name of the destination page) to link the language versions to this article.

Best!